# There's a bug with Search and Pagination in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building my site in React and I have created pagination and search. When I search for something on the site, it only works when after that I go to another page. I think this is due to the fact that Softwares and Pagination are in the same component.

Then I tried lifting-state-up, but I got an error: React Minified Error # 31.

Here's Pagination component:

```js
const Paginator = ({
    total, // Total records
    startPage = 1,
    totalPages = null,
    onMovePage = null,
  }) => {

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <section id={styles.paginator}>

        <Header/>

        ...

        {range(1, totalPages+1).map(p => (
          <PagItem key={p} handleClick={ () => {setCurrentPage(p); onMovePage && onMovePage({currentPage: p})} } title={p} name={p} />
        ))}

        ...
      </section>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here's Softwares component:

```js
const Softwares = ({ search }) => {

  const [softwares, setSoftwares] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(null);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async ({ currentPage }) => {

    const SEARCH = search ? `?search=${search}` : '';
    const CURRENT_PAGE = currentPage && SEARCH === '' ? `?page=${currentPage}` : '';

    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/${CURRENT_PAGE}${SEARCH}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    setSoftwares(data.results);
    setTotal(data.count);
    setTotalPages(data.total_pages);
    setValid(true);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({ currentPage: 1 });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {
      valid &&
      <section className={styles.softwares}>
        <Header header={"new softwares"} />
        {softwares.map(s => (
          <Article key={s.id} pathname={s.id} title={s.title} image={s.image} pubdate={s.pub_date} icon={s.category.parent.img} categoryID={s.category.id} categoryName={s.category.name} dCount={s.counter} content={s.content} />
        ))}
        <Paginator totalPages={totalPages} total={total} onMovePage={fetchData} />
      </section>
    }
    </>
  );
};
```

SearchForm in Header component:

```js
const Header = ({ handleChange, handleClick }) => {

  return (
    ...

        <SearchForm handleChange={handleChange} handleClick={handleClick} />

    ...
  );
};

const SearchForm = ({ style, handleChange, handleClick }) => {

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <SearchButton onClick={handleClick} />
        <small>ENTER</small>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

const SearchButton = ({onClick }) => {
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
    </button>
  );
};
```

And part of Search in App component:

```js
const App = () => {

    ...
    
    // Search
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    if (shouldFetch) {

      (async () => {

        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/?search=${search}`);

        const data = await response.json();

        setShouldFetch(false);

      })()

    }

  }, [shouldFetch]);

  const handleClick = () => setShouldFetch(true);

    return (
        <div className="App">

      <Header handleChange={handleChange} handleClick={handleClick} />

      ...

      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact render={props => <Softwares {...props} search={search} />} />
      </Switch>

            {/* Actually I'd like to use Paginator here, but it 
                    throws the error: React Minified Error # 31 */}

            ...

    </div>
    );

}
```

So, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `useEffect` dependencies (or lack thereof).

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
const Softwares = ({ search }) => {

  const [softwares, setSoftwares] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(null);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = async ({ currentPage }) => {

    const SEARCH = search ? `?search=${search}` : '';
    const CURRENT_PAGE = currentPage && SEARCH === '' ? `?page=${currentPage}` : '';

    const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/${CURRENT_PAGE}${SEARCH}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    setSoftwares(data.results);
    setTotal(data.count);
    setTotalPages(data.total_pages);
    setValid(true);

  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({ currentPage: 1 });
  }, []);
```

The empty dependency array means that you are running the effect that calls `fetchData` one time when the component mounts.  Clicks in the `Pagination` component will call the `fetchData` function directly.  Changes to `search` **do not cause `fetchData` to re-run**.  The data depends on the `search` so `search` should be a dependency.

The `fetchData` function is fine in this component.  The state that I would recommend lifting up is to lift the `currentPage` up from `Pagination` into `Softwares`.  The `onMovePage` callback can just update the `currentPage` state.  That way you can call `fetchData` only through your effect and run the effect whenever *either* `search` or `currentPage` changes.

```
const Softwares = ({ search }) => {

  const [softwares, setSoftwares] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(null);
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // defining the function inside of the useEffect
    // lets eslint exhaustive dependency checks work their magic
    const fetchData = async () => {

      const SEARCH = search ? `?search=${search}` : '';
      const CURRENT_PAGE = currentPage && SEARCH === '' ? `?page=${currentPage}` : '';
  
      const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/software/${CURRENT_PAGE}${SEARCH}`);
  
      const data = await response.json();
  
      setSoftwares(data.results);
      setTotal(data.count);
      setTotalPages(data.total_pages);
      setValid(true);
    }
  
    // need to define and call in separate steps when using async functions
    fetchData();

  }, [currentPage, search]);

  return (
    ...
        <Paginator page={currentPage} totalPages={totalPages} total={total} onMovePage={setCurrentPage} />
    ...
  );
};
```